# Why won't access return the correct values within the date range?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The query it not handling the date ranges correctly.

I have a table with values stored like "01/10/2013 11:00:00 PM" for DateStamp. Ranging from 25/09/2013 1:00:00 AM to 02/10/2013.

The textboxs values are dtBegin = "28/09/2013" and dtEnd = 01/10/2013.

```
dSumUsuage = DSum("Average", "tblScadaHourly", "[DateStamp] >=  #" & dtBegin & "#" & " AND " & "[DateStamp] <  #" & dtEnd & "#" & " AND ([Station] ='" & sStationName & "')")
```

This query is returning an error of "Invalid use of Null". But their is data between these dates and for that station name.

Comment: Your dSumUsuage is of type Date, it does not accept Null, as no records meets your WHERE constraints.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a classical Access date formatting error: When using the english date format with slashes, Access thinks that you use the format MM/DD/YYYY, unless this results in an invalid date (then it tries DD/MM/YYYY).

Therefore, I prefer using the international date format YYYY-MM-DD.

In your case, this might result in a query for ">=2013-09-28 And <2013-01-10", which obviously can't return any results. >> with the international format, it would ask for ">=2013-09-28 And <2013-10-01"

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer, your where string is malformed, as Your dSumUsuage is of type Date, it does not accept Null, as no records meet your bad WHERE constraints, so an error is raised.

We use this procedure:

```
Public Function FormatDateTimeVb(ByVal varDateTime)
  FormatDateTimeVb = "#" &  Format(varDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & "#"
End Function
```

Using this function to form date time string, now we get the sum of tblScadaHourly.Average:

```
dSumUsuage = DSum("Average", "tblScadaHourly", _
  "[DateStamp] >= " & FormatDateTimeVb(dtBegin) _
  & " AND [DateStamp] < " & FormatDateTimeVb(dtEnd) _
  & " AND ([Station] = '" & sStationName & "')")
```